# Best practice to encourage error / bug reporting of JavaScript app?

Tags: javascript, bug-tracking

I have written a JavaScript app / tool (on a website) that has some fairly involved logic and user interfaces. Users will themselves be developers.

What is the best way to encourage users to report problems?

My current thinking is to avoid any sort of bug tracking application. Instead, just provide an extremely simple contact form with no mandatory fields. Users can provide as little information as they wish.

Has anyone found this to be a sensible approach? Can anyone provide some recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, I know - but for logging/bug tracking you can make Ajax requests (unobtrusively) behind the scenes and pass log information as parameters, then log that info to a file, database, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Get the feedback or problem through the simple interface as you suggested. At the backend link those to a simple bug/issue tracker. No need to re-invent / re-implement the problem/issue/bug tracking.